# Needed acceleration input to reach a target point

Tags: kinematics, acceleration

I have a point mass traveling on a 2D plane with some initial velocity `v` and initial position `r`. The point mass is able to accelerate in any direction on that plane up to acceleration amount `a`

If I wanted to calculate a family of solutions for reaching a target point `R` in shortest (or short) time, how could I do it? By a solution I mean directions and accelerations the point mass should have in time to reach the target.

First idea I have is to accelerate the mass in direction perpendicular to the speed to rotate towards the target and then maximum acceleration towards target till midpoint distance, reverse, maximum deceleration.

Is there a generic solution for this problem though?

I presume it is already a solved problem (taking into account that we have space probes) but I cannot find any leads anywhere...

Comment: I believe you're asking about the [calculus of variations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calculus_of_variations). I'm not an expert on this so I can't really answer your question, sorry!

Comment: Hey, thanks! I think that is what I'm looking for. If someone had something a bit more specific (e.g. links to papers) I would really appreciate, but thanks to you now I know where to start.

Comment: I'm a little confused by this question though. Why would a straight line not always be the best solution here?

Comment: Well Euler created calculus of variations based on the solution to a similar problem, which was to find the curve which leads a point under gravitational force to the end in the minimal time. The formulation should be usable for you: [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brachistochrone_curve)

Comment: @barrycarter - if the initial velocity is not pointing at the target point, then a straight line would not be enough. Also, ideally I am looking for a way to find acceleration in time needed for the body to get to target, not only the path's shape.

Comment: I actually meant a straight line towards the target from the current position, but it turns out that's completely wrong and will simply end up putting you in orbit around the target. Working on a hopefully better solution.